# Benefit of migrating to GIT from git-over-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, smartgit

I am thinking about converting my svn repository on my server to git, but I am not sure what would be the benefit for me, since I already use [SmartGit/hg](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) which creates a local git repository and commits all local git commits through to svn already.

As far as I can see, there is no real need for me here to migrate over to git.

So what would be the benefit for me and my collegues that all use only SmartGit/hg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SmartGit but I know about the usual disadvantages when using git as an SVN client, so I will talk about that.

Switching to a remote git repository would allow you to effectively use a `branch` and `merge` heavy workflow.

What does that mean?

In SVN you usually have a single branch where all work gets committed; git on the other hand enables to branch and merge a lot easier, which allows to efficiently use a workflow with multiple branches.

For example you could use a `master` branch and a `development` branch. Only stable versions get merged into `master` while the development process takes place on the `development` branch. Furthermore you can create `feature` branches which are bound to a specific topic and all commits are done on this `feature` branch until the topic is finished; then you can merge the changes introduced by the feature into the `development` branch and later on as a release into the `master` branch.

Why isn't this possible using an SVN repository?

Git handles merges differently than SVN; in Git a merge is a commit which has multiple parent commits. This isn't possible in SVN, in SVN every commit has a single parent, never more.

So if you push merge commits to an SVN repository the merge history gets lost. While you will keep the merge history your colleagues would only see one big commit which introduced all changes from the commits of your merged branch. You lose information.
This is the reason why it's recommended to only use `rebase` rather than `merge` when interacting with an SVN repository.

---

This is one advantage using git with a remote git repository rather than an SVN one. You can find more if you search.

Comment: Can't I use this development branch with SVN? If I keep the branch, I will keep the information about the single commits and parents too, won't I?

Comment: @Zeeker " In SVN it's not easily possible to merge a branch and then keep commiting to it" - WTF?! RTFM!!! `--reintegrate` doesn't prohibit using branch even in 1.7 (contrary to 1.6), 1.8+ made sync-merging even simplier

Comment: @LazyBadger I'll admit that I'm not as familiar with SVN as with Git, my last information on this topic is that it's not easily done, but it's totally possible that this has changed and is no longer true. Nethertheless does git provide a far easier way to merge and branch than SVN does.

Comment: @rubo77 And even if you would create a SVN branch called `develop` you wouldn't be able to easily use the advantages of `feature` branches, since you would have to create SVN branches for them, at least if you would like to keep the history and to use `merge`. Of course you would be able to use `rebase` for `feature` branches.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem to create brances in my SVN, there is enough HDD space. So it seems then there is no disadvantage, when I stay on SVN on the server side forever?

Comment: @rubo77 `feature` branches are usually very short lived, sometimes just a few hours, but like I said, you could easily use `rebase` in this case. So `feature` branches would be `rebased` on top of `development` while `development` would be `merged` into `master` (or whatever). As long as you don't have problems with the current setup I see no harm in keeping it that way.

Answer (score 1):

With pure Git solution you'll get following benefits

- Fewer links in the chain (1 is better than 3) is more reliability of system in common
- Avoiding the usage of foreign systems means *no translation* of data, transferred between systems (less chance of distortion)